# How do I kill Esbern and Delphine with console commands?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to kill Esbern and Delphine. I've tried using console commands, but it won't work (`setessential baseID 0...<0>`). I've also tried clicking on them.

I know how to press <kbd>~</kbd> - it shows up and I can type it in, but it keeps saying "not found" or "missing". Can a kind person out there lend a hand?

Comment: why do you want to kill them?

Answer (score 2):

There are a plethora of mods on Nexus Mods for making everybody in the game non-essential, but if you don't want to download anything follow these instructions:

1. Press tilde key <kbd>~</kbd>
2. Type `help "Esbern"` (include the quotation marks)
3. The display should show `NPC_: 00013358`, that is his BaseID.
4. Type `setessential 13358 0`
5. Type `kill 13358`
6. Depending on what stage of the main quest you're at, Esbern and Delphine may not die even if you set them to non-essential and the only way to kill them in that situation is to use a mod.

Answer (score 1):

The BaseID for [Esbern](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Esbern_(Skyrim)) 00013358 is and [Delphine](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Delphine) is 00013478.

This should allow you to set them to not essential:

```
setessential 00013358 0
setessential 00013478 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This post on [killing Jarl Balgruuf](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121863/how-do-i-kill-the-jarl/121869#121869) includes the procedure for setting essential NPCs to non-essential. You seem to have the basics down, although you do not click on the character you want to set to non-essential. You just use the correct BaseID. You probably haven't used the correct one. Delphine's BaseID is 00013478.

Notice that the answer to the linked question mentions that killing an essential NPC will almost certainly break your savegame. So, you may not want to do it.