# Any way to make it so that i can kill anybody in Fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

By this I mean killing the npcs that have immunity and get right back up.
If there is any way to modify the file or mods .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the point of this question is. I mean, you can do anything through modding or modifying the game's files. People have turned GTA 4 into Watch_Dogs by modding the game, and if you replace all the game's files with those of another app, you could even turn Solitaire into Windows 10. If you're asking which mod lets you kill essential NPCs, that would be a software-rec and off-topic.

Comment: @Nolonar I'm reading this as being something like [this guy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/121863/how-do-i-kill-the-jarl). It's asking how to remove the essential flag from NPCs. Which so far as far as I can tell isn't possible in-game, but I haven't been able to test `setessential` for myself

Comment: This is my reading as well.

Answer (score 3):

Almost certainly not [yet].

Keep in mind, even if you can change the "essential" attribute to make plot-essential characters killable, Bethesda's Fallout games are coded to prevent hostile or potentially hostility-provocing actions against children.  [In Fallout 3, it took a user a user-created game mod to restore the ability to kill children](http://www.nexusmods.com/fallout3/mods/18738/), and both Fallout: New Vegas and Fallout 4 have that same hard-coded idiosyncratic stupi...  ... "behavior."

(And, ugh, what a dumb design decision the whole no kid killing thing is.  One of my fondest memories in Fallout 2 was when the shock of noticing my [Childkiller reputation](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Childkiller) - I accidentally clipped a couple kids with the blast radius of a rocket I fired early on in the game, for which I was punished by bounty hunter attacks and worse prices when trading.  Brilliant!  Certainly much better than the idea of jamming a bunch of invulnerable NPCs into the game that do nothing but get in the way and annoy me.)

Comment: Not to mention there's nothing more satisfying than shoving a mini nuke down Mayor MacCready's obnoxious throat

Comment: The rant's a bit off-topic. I could see plenty of people not upvoting due to that.

Comment: @DCShannon  And...? I already have about 50,000 StackExchange brand valueless internet points. What am I going to do with 10 more?  Or 10 million more, for that matter? The path to web Zen begins with realizing that these valueless internet points ("rep" on StackExchange)  are valueless and just about worthless.  (At least for the person _with_ the valueless internet points, that is.)

Comment: @HopelessN00b I assume you want to make a question that others value and find useful. Forgive me if that's not the case. You have a fairly low rep count on this particular SE, so I also assume you're interested in getting more privileges so you can better contribute. Perhaps not.

Comment: @DCShannon That last one. I'm long past that point of caring about privs or being able to contribute better.  Been there, done that (at the highest possible level, I'm an ex-moderator), and figured out that getting more privileges just amounts to additional unpaid effort on my part that serves to make money for someone else.